# Can I upgrade the RAM on my 2011 MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, memory

I am planning to purchase a used MacBook Pro from someone, and the configuration is as mentioned:

- MacBook Pro 15" (A1286) Late 2011
- i7 2,2 GHz
- 8 GB RAM
- 500 GB HDD

Will I be able to upgrade the RAM to 16 GB for this model of MacBook?

Comment: You can go to [EveryMac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.2-15-late-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html#macspecs4) and lookup the specs via serial number.  This will tell you what's upgradable and what's not.

Comment: I find this is upgradable. Can you also confirm if possible?

Comment: I can't because I don't have the same laptop.  I'd just go to the same site I gave you.  This is a pretty authoritative site so I'd believe what they tell you.

Comment: iFixit agrees and says it is easy - see [MacBook Pro 15" Unibody Late 2011 RAM Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+Late+2011+RAM+Replacement/7529)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the mentioned model of MacBook Pro is user upgradable.

The maximum RAM supported by the Late 2011 MacBook Pro is 16 GB. You can refer to the specifications for this model here:

- [Table of second generation MacBook Pro models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Technical_specifications_2)

Look for the column corresponding to the mentioned model (Late 2011).

> Memory                       4 GB (two 2 GB)
>
> **(Two slots)**                 Expandable to 16 GB